# Button not doing anything if clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm making an **Etch-a-Sketch** project and when I click the black button, it works. The background color of the squares turns black when hovered. But when I click the **rainbow button** it **doesn't work**. It should change the background color of the squares to a random color when hovered.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button id="black" class="btn" onclick="changeColor('black')"> <span> Black</span> </button>
<button id="rainbow" class="btn" onclick="changeColor('random')"> <span> Rainbow</span></button>
```

Here's the JS:

```
 let color = "black";

      function getColor(){
        if(true){
          if(color === "random"){
            let value = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var random = "#";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
          color += value[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        this.style.backgroundColor = random;
          } else{
            this.style.backgroundColor = color;
          }
        }
      }
    
      function changeColor(select){
        color = select;
      }
```

The `getColor()` function is called in `getGrid(size)` function. Like this: `square.addEventListener("mouseover", getColor);`

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JaredDev/w2kgubLq/6/

What should I do to make the **rainbow button** generate a **random background color** to a square/pixel when hovered?

Comment: what is the purpose of `if(ture) { ... }`? i don't think that if statement is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you generate a random color, you store it in `color` which will become `color = "random{some random string}"` and then you assign `random = "#"` to `this.style.backgroundColor`. you need to assign the random color to `random`.

```
...
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    random += value[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
...
```